# Protractor : ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, testcasesource

I wrote test cases three months back at that time they worked fine now i want to run those test cases in another system so i did basic setup. When i try to run protractor test case now they are failing with 'Unable to start a WebDriver session'. I have tried so many solutions but they didn't work for me.
Here i am attaching my protractor.conf.js file and error details.

> protractor.conf.js

```
'use strict';

exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || '3036'),

chromeOnly: true,

// To get the maximimum test screen size
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
},

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
specs: [
'e2e/attributeSection/search_spec.js', 'e2e/attributeSection/create_spec.js', 
'e2e/attributeSection/edit_spec.js', 'e2e/attribute/search_spec.js', 
'e2e/attribute/create_spec.js', 'e2e/attribute/edit_spec.js',
'e2e/classification/search_spec.js', 'e2e/classification/create_spec.js', 
'e2e/classification/edit_spec.js', 'e2e/classificationGroup/create_spec.js', 
'e2e/classificationGroup/edit_spec.js'
],

exclude: [],

capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
    binary: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    args: [],
    extensions: [],
}
},

framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
}
};
```

> Error in console

```
Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

C:\Users\Cronj-  4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145
  callback(new Error(message));
           ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:441:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:155:22)
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:129:30)
at [object Object].Builder.build (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:416:22)
at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:38:7)
at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:180:37)
at C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:257:21
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Cronj-4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
```

Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you do `webdriver-manager update` and try running the tests again?

Comment: Also, which `protractor` version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe i got these results                                                 D:\cronj\ca\27-03-2015>webdriver-manager update
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

D:\cronj\ca\27-03-2015>protractor --version
Version 2.0.0

Comment: Try with the earlier version of protractor to rule out setup issues. From the error it ooks like an issue with the `webdriver-manager`. Can you share the logs from the window where you are running `webdriver-manager start`?

Comment: @RahulVig, I ran webdriver-manager start in one command prompt and protractor in another command prompt then only it was working. I want to know reason behind that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran webdriver-manager start in one command prompt and protractor in another command prompt then only test cases started running

Answer (score 5):

I believe the "chromeOnly" option got deprecated in v2.0.0.

```
chromeOnly: true,
```

This used to mean use "direct" mode without a selenium server.  But since both firefox and chrome support direct mode, the property was renamed to "directConnect".  So change that line to:

```
directConnect: true,
```

In this mode you don't need a selenium server, so you can drop the `seleniumAddress` property which is just confusing folks.

See https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1933/files